# How do I compute the eigenfunctions of the Fourier Transform?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

In Andy's answer to the question "[What are fixed points of the Fourier Transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform)" on Math Overflow, he shows that the Fourier Transform has eigenvalues $\{+1, +i, -1, -i \}$ and that the projections of any function onto the corresponding four eigenspaces may be found through some simple linear algebra.

I would like to get a better feeling for these four eigenspaces of the fourier transform.

1. How can I find some interesting members of each of these eigenspaces?
2. How can I show that Hermite-Gaussians are in one (or more?) of the eigenspaces?
3. How can one define usable projection operators onto these eigenspaces?
4. The wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Eigenfunctions) on the Fourier Transform mentions that Wiener defined the Fourier Transform via these projections.  What exactly was Wiener's approach?

Answer (score 8):

One method is to apply the [Bargmann transform:](https://planetmath.org/BargmannTransform)

$$B_f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \exp \left(2 \pi x z - \pi x^2 - \frac{\pi}{2}z^2 \right) dy$$

to the eigenvalue equation:

$$f(x) = \lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y) \exp(-2 \pi ix y) dy$$

to obtain the following relation for the Bargmann transformed eigenfunctions:

$$B_f(z) = \lambda B_f(-iz) $$

whose solutions are the monomials:

$B_f(z) = z^n$, corresponding to the eigenvalues $i^{n \bmod{4}}$.

Now, the inverse Bargmann transform of the monomials are just the Hermite functions.

*Remark:* The application of the Bargmann transform to the eigenvalue equation entails a change of the integration order which is possible because the Hermite functions are bounded.

The projection operators onto the $n$th subspace in the Bargamann
representation are given by the kernels

$$ P(v,\bar{z})=\frac{(v\bar{z})^n}{n!} ,$$

which act on the Bargmann transformed functions according to:

$$ Pf(v) = \int_{\mathbb{C}}P(v,\bar{z}) f(z) \exp(-z\bar{z})dzd\bar{z} .$$

In the time domain the projection kernels are just $P(t, \tau) = H_n(\tau) H_n(t)$ due to the orthonormality of the Hermite functions.

Comment: Why would this give all possible eigenfunctions?

Comment: The sum of the projection kernels $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(v,\bar{z})=exp(v\bar{z})$ is just the reproducing kernel of the Bargmann space, thus the eigenfunctions constitute of a complete basis of the Bargmann space