# Solving $\widehat{f}=f$ with $f\in L^2$.

Tags: fourier-transform

The following question arose. What functions do they satisfy?
$\widehat{f}=f$ with $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Only the function $f=0$?

Comment: gaussian too. explicitly which i believe depends on your convention for the FT

Comment: $\widehat{f}(x):=\int \mathrm{e}^{-ix\cdot \xi} f(\xi)d\xi$

Comment: and also there should be some of the form poly * that gaussian, since poly turns to derivatives which then become poly again. Going to guess hermite polys

Comment: Is the following valid?
$f=\check{f} \Rightarrow \widehat{f}=\check{f} \Rightarrow \widehat{(\widehat{f})}=f\Rightarrow f(-x)=f(x)$?

Comment: Hermite functions of degree a multiple of 4.  Google "hermite functions as eigenvectors of fourier transform."

Comment: There are many functions that are fixed points of the Fourier transform. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform

Comment: Also see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118078/which-functions-fourier-transform-is-the-function-itself